# lat/lon conversion 8 digits

Tags: python, latitude-longitude

I have 8 digit lat/long

```
12345678, -34567890 as an example
```

How can I convert them to decimal?

Something like 12.345678, -34.567890

Can I assume a decimal after the first 2 digits?
I was confused on the initial format with 8 digits.
How can I convert them to decimal?

```
def dd2dms(deg):
    d = int(deg)
    md = abs(deg - d) * 60
    m = int(md)
    sd = (md - m) * 60
    return [d, m, sd]
print(dd2dms(12345678))

result: 12345678
```

If assuming 2 decimal spots then:

```
print(dd2dms(12.345678))

result: [12,20,44.4407...]
```

UPDATE:

I found that I can just divide by 1e6

Comment: Hi! Please show some code you have tried.

Comment: Your question needs more context (what is the *source* of these numbers?), but note that longitude can exceed 100, so I don't think that assuming that the decimal place is after the second number is always safe

Comment: You need to find out what produced those values and see what was *intended*.

Comment: @JohnColeman Indeed, values less than 10 (or even 1) are also legitimate.

Comment: I did some online search and have found no mention of such decimal-point free formats. It doesn't seem to be very standard.

Comment: you mean you have one number and you want two numbers(lat, long) in output!

Comment: @JainilPatel I have two numbers each 8 digits one lat one long

Comment: so you have to pass two numbers to function, not just degree.----- def dd2dms(lat,long)

Comment: tell me where did you find such coordinates?

Comment: degrees and decimal minutes: 40° 26.767′ N 79° 58.933′ W     something like this? 8 digits?

Comment: sexagesimal degree: degrees, minutes, and seconds : 40° 26′ 46″ N 79° 58′ 56″ W   or like this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as "unclear". It is pointless to speculate about the meaning of an unspecified format. The question is too ambiguous to answer.

Comment: he didnot specified the format of input aswell as output.

Comment: `12345678` could be `1.2345678` degrees longitude, `12.345678` degrees, `123.45678` degrees, or in sexagesimal `12h34m56s78`, or even `12d34m56s78` longitude etc etc. Too many options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends how you have the digits, but you could probably just divide by 1e6 in your particular case as it seems there are six decimal points:

```
coords = (12345678, -34567890)
latitude, longitude = (i/1e6 for i in coords)
print(latitude, longitude)
```

You can't just assume a decimal after the first two digits, because -1.625730 is a valid longitude (for example).

Answer (score 0):

If you search in your browser for "8-digit latitutde longitude", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

The immediate answer to your question is that these are standard lat/long coordinates with six decimal places.  The inputs will vary from 0.000000 to 179.999999 in magnitude (well, 180.000000), so you can have 7 or 9 digits, as well.

Check [here](http://n1sv.com/PROJECTS/How%20to%20calculate%20your%208-digit%20grid%20square.pdf) for excruciating detail.

Comment: Your link appears to be a different format; the OP mentions nothing about 8-character values that can include letters.

Comment: This is plausible, but not consistent with OP's stipulation that the 8-digit integer values are used. It is possible (perhaps even probable) that OP has made a hasty generalization from some 8-digit examples to all locations being expressible in 8 digits.